# iTunes App Approval Requirements with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, itunes

What requirements should I be aware of when submitting an iOS app that is built with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap? All of the content (HTML, images, etc.) for each page of the app is provided by a remote server and that is where I am concerned about rejection. Is it OK to be loading all the content this way?

As best I can tell, I think I just need to make sure the app will load an initial page on the device without an internet connection. I don't think it needs to provide much functionality without an internet connection, but I would appreciate any insight into what is required to meet the app guidelines for this type of app.

Here is one of the app store guidelines that made me concerned, although I'm assuming they mean Xcode and not HTML.

- Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected

And this makes me think everything is OK.

- Apps that browse the web must use the iOS WebKit framework and WebKit
  Javascript

Answer (score 3):

> Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected

You do not need to worry about this if you are downloading anycode that is still executed in a webview javascript is definitely fine. You will not be rejected for this.

Now your bigger concern would be that your app needs to differentiate itself from a standard web app. Why do you need your app to be native? and not just use the meta tag from Jasper (great example btw). The number 1 reason Phonegap apps get rejected is that they are just regular websites wrapped in Phonegap.

But it's really not that hard to find compelling reasons to have your app be native. Just because you don't download any files to the local machine doesn't mean that you will be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

If you app is just a wrapper for a website then you could use the following meta tag to allow users to add an icon to their Home Screen:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

You can set your icon and startup image as well, check-out this documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

As far as uploading your app to the iTunes Store, I know you can use web-services to download information into your app (I have an app that does this with Phonegap) but I believe they will deny your app if it does nothing more than display a webpage that has to download every time it's run.